# How to trigger the same action on 3 android emulators and 1 iOS emulator at the same time?

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, automated-tests, emulation

Currently I'm trying to set up a testing environment for researching purposes. What I'm trying to achieve is the following situation: 
I would like to run 3 Android apps and 1 iOS app using emulators on my macbook. They are apps with a similar UI, but a different code behind. I would like to start the same action on all emulators at the same time, like pressing a button or calling a method.

I already tried to run the apps on the emulators and let them listen to a changing value in a realtime database on Firebase, so every time I changed the value in Firebase, all the apps would call the method. The problem with this set up is the delay between the apps because they rely on a stable internet connection.

Is there any other solution to trigger the action on all emulators at the same time? I would really appreciate the help!

Thanks

Edit based on answers and comments:
- I would like to choose whenever I want to run the action on the apps. This means that e.g. an alarm manager is a less preferable solution.
- I would like to avoid external network calls.

Answer (score 1):

1)Try to use GCM/FCM and send command from server to all the emulators/devices and call the method on that GCM command.

2) Set the alarm using alarm manger for the particular time and call a method on that time.

Comment: thanks for the answer, really appreciate it! Isn't GCM/FCM also relying on a stable network? And I like the alarm manager solution but I would like to call the action on the apps whenever I want to, not by a fixed moment in time...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in android using AlarmManager.

It will run at 18:32 (Set the time to future and run code on 3 android emulators, make sure all devices have same time)

```
Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());//set the current time and date for this calendar

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 32);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileList.this, IntentBroadcastedReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(ProfileList.this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pintent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really appreciate it! I like the alarm manager solution but I would like to call the action on the apps whenever I want to, not by a fixed moment in time...